# CELL() formula is returning an error in a popup window even though it is correct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have experienced this same issue in other formulas as well on this installation of MS Excel. This is the formula:[image]

And this is the error message: [image]

I'm running Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2401 Build 16.0.17231.20194) 32-bit

I read through the documentation and some examples, and it seems that this is both basic and matching the syntax. Then, I tried rewriting the formula thinking it might be some ASCII/character encoding problem with the standard qwerty keyboard I'm using to type.

T have checked the CONCAT() formula inside, this is the formula and its output. It is correct:[image][image]

Comment: @ScottCraner just saw your comment after I finished posting my (similar) asnwer, but why didn't you post it as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing INDIRECT with CELL:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCAT(...))
```

One note, since INDIRECT and CELL are both volatile they should be avoided if possible.  On way, since your sheet is hard coded is to use index (this requires that the value in AF22 to be a column NUMBER and not a string)

```
=INDEX('HMB Data'!A:XAA,D24,AF22)
```

This avoids the volatility.

Comment: `=LET(x,CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)),y,TOCOL(x&TOROW(x)),z,VSTACK(x,y,TOCOL(y&TOROW(x))),index('HMB Data'!$A:$XFD,D24,XMATCH(AF22,z)))` would work if AF22 contains the string as in the example. But using the number is much easier.

Comment: Your answer is probably good enough for the use case and mine is adding the column reference with a trick to still be able to use the string. Not sure what a wiki means.

Answer (score 2):

Encouraged by Scott I decided to post my comment as an answer:

To avoid volatile function, such as INDIRECT which may be the most obvious to solve your usecase, we could in this case also use a non-volatile version:

```
=LET(x,CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)),y,TOCOL(x&TOROW(x)),z,VSTACK(x,y,TOCOL(y&TOROW(x))),
INDEX('HMB Data'!$A:$XFD,D24,XMATCH(AF22,z)))
```

This first declares `x` to be capital `A` to `Z` for columns 1 to 26.

Next `y` is declared to create a combination for the columns `AA` to `ZZ` by using `x&TOROW(x)`, which spills all combinations of `A` with `A-Z`, `B` with `A-Z`, etc. wrapped in `TOCOL` to flatten that.

`z` is used to `VSTACK` `x`, `y` and the combinations of `y` and `x`: `y&TOROW(x)` to get all combinations of `AA` with `A-Z` to `ZZ` with `A-Z`.

Since `XFD` is the last column of Excel and there are enough rows to be able to stack `x`, `y` and `z`, we can use that to lookup the string of the column letters: `XMATCH(AF22,z)`

Which returns the column number of `AF22` and can be used perfectly in `INDEX`.